# Missing Xcode features

Tags: xcode

I am new to iOS (Swift) development. I did a little research and found out that Xcode doesn't support basic features related to autocorrection or other handy staff such as

1. Add missing imports
2. Auto alignment + space correction
3. Remove the entire line (Ctrl-X)

According to the first point, I found this article https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/79007 where developers complain about this missing feature, I would like to know if something changed today?

---

And about the second point, I see there is `Ctrl-i` command that can help to correct the lines in case if the line is too close to the boarders, BUT if there is redundant\missing space (eg:`var material:SCNMaterial{get}`) OR case like this

```
class Foo{
    func update()}
```

nothing will be changed.

---

The last one is just a handy staff that I liked in other IDEs is `Ctrl-Z` cmd, when you need to remove a few lines you can just put a pointer on the line and click the combination as a result this line will be cut, BUT not in Xcode, here it is necessary to mark exactly the text you are going to cut (sometimes it is annoying).

Let me know if I am wrong?

Comment: **Add missing imports** is a feature in **Xcode 13 beta**. You are correct on #2 & #3.

Comment: For alignment (and other) corrections I recommend [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) and [SwiftFormat](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwiftFormat).